# Structure sheaf is ample

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have the following question. It is a well-known fact that if $X=\operatorname{Spec} A$ is the spectrum of a ring then $\mathcal{O}_{X}$ is ample. Let us suppose that $X$ is any scheme and $\mathcal{A}$ is a quasi-coherent sheaf of algebras. Is it the structure sheaf of $\underline{\operatorname{Spec}}(\mathcal{A})$ ample?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Ampleness seems to me to be a relative condition. Often we refer to ampleness over a field for example, in which case this well known fact is false, since it would imply all affine varieties are also projective. If you mean $\mathcal{O}_X$ is ample for $X$ over the base scheme $X$, that's probably true, but you should be a little more specific I think.

Comment: Do you know an example where $\mathcal{O}_X$ is not ample? If so, what happens if you take $\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{O}_X$?

Comment: Umm thank you for your hint Mohan, now is clear. Sorry for this dumb question.

Comment: If you've figured this out, please consider answering your own question below for the benefit of future readers (and also to remove this from the unanswered queue).

Answer (score 1):

***Solution***: Let us suppose that $X$ is a scheme such that $\mathcal{O}_{X}$ is not ample. Let us consider the spectrum of the structural sheaf, $\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}_{X}=X$. Therefore, the structure sheaf of $\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{X}$ is not ample.

Thank you Mohan for the hint.